# Authentication problem while POST request to Dydra using Python

Tags: python, sparql

Authentication is failing while trying to insert new entry into Dydra SPARQL endpoint. While using select statement everything is working fine. Do you have any idea why?

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

insert_query = """INSERT DATA
{
  <http://dydra.com/cornelpaul/rout/sparql/personsRoot/__Python_User> foaf:name "__X__";
                         foaf:nick "Python_nick";
                         rdf:type foaf:Person.
}
"""

select_query = """SELECT ?persoana
WHERE {
?persoana rdf:type foaf:Person;
}
"""

dydra_api_key = "PZEI7LyVitRuvrVyqhnB"


sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://dydra.com/cornelpaul/rout/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
sparql.setCredentials(dydra_api_key, dydra_api_key)
sparql.method = "POST"
# sparql.method = "GET"


sparql.setQuery(insert_query)

results = sparql.query().convert()
print(len(results["results"]["bindings"]))
for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result)
```

Comment: do you resp. the user has permission for write operations? Did you try it form CLI e.g. via `curl` to try it without Python first?

Comment: I tried it with a requester client and the result is the same. So it seems the problem comes from Dydra and it's not something related to Python. The thing is that I don't know how to manage this from Dydra in order to give access for update requests. Does anyone have experience with Dydra?

Comment: Ok, at least we know now that it's not Python related. And yeah, that's why I was asking, did you setup the permissions for the user? The docs are online: https://api.dydra.com/authorization/index.html

Comment: I tried everything in the docs, authentication with api-key, user and password but without any luck.. I'm actually blocked by this thing and I'm very curious if anyone managed to do a POST request with success to Dydra...